# I would like to know if this particular orthonormal set is an orthonormal basis.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, orthogonality

It is straightworward to see that $$\Biggl\{\frac {\sin (mx)}{1+m^2}\Biggr\}$$ is an orthonormal set with respect to the norm 
$$\|u\|^2=\int_0^{2\pi}|u|^2+|\nabla u|^2$$ (i.e. the norm in the Sobolev space $H^1$).

Does this set generate $H_0^1$? (the closure of $C_0^\infty$ in $H^1$).

If so, how can this be shown? If not, is there a (natural) way to extend this to a basis of $H_0^1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed half of them. You need the normalized half-period functions $\sin(nx/2)$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. These are the solutions of the Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem
$$
                  -f'' = \lambda f,\\
                    f(0)=0,\;\;f(2\pi)=0.
$$
The eigenvalues are $\lambda = (n/2)^{2}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, and the normalized eigenfunctions $\sin(nx/2)$ form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$.

For $f \in H_{0}^{1}$ and $g_{n}=\sin(nx/2)$, the Sobolev inner-product is
$$
    (f,g_{n})_{S}=(f,g_{n})_2+(f',g_{n}')_2=(f,g_{n}-g_{n}'')_2=(1+(n/2)^{2})(f,g_{n})_2.
$$
Therefore, if $(f,g_{n})_S=0$ for all $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, then $(f,g_{n})_2=0$ for $n=1,2,3\cdots$, which guarantees that $f=0$ a.e.. So the normalized eigenfunctions are complete in $H_{0}^{1}$.